# grep only some repeat part of log

Tags: grep

I have log like that:

```
---------
Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff1
------
SomeStuff2
SomeStuff3
---------
Mycode_is-526-132
SomeStuff4
------
SomeStuff5
SomeStuff6
---------
Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff7
------
SomeStuff8
SomeStuff9
---------
```

I want parse this file and grep only part from `--------- to ---------` with code 546-432:

```
---------
Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff1
------
SomeStuff2
SomeStuff3
---------
```

and

```
---------
Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff7
------
SomeStuff8
SomeStuff9
---------
```

Tried used something like this:

```
grep -Pzo '\-{6}\n.+Mycode_is\-546\-432(\n|.)*\-{4}(\n|.)*\-{6}'
```

But this doesn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An `gnu awk` (gnu due to multiple characters in RS) soulution

```
awk -v RS="Mycode" '/546-432/{print RS $0}' file
Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff1
------
SomeStuff2
SomeStuff3
---------

Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff7
------
SomeStuff8
SomeStuff9
---------
```

By setting Record Selector to `Mycode`, it will make a bulk of data from `Mycode` to `Mycode`, then we search for data `/546-432/`

A shorter version, but not as good formatting:

```
awk -v RS="---------" '/546-432/' file

Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff1
------
SomeStuff2
SomeStuff3


Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff7
------
SomeStuff8
SomeStuff9
```

Another small variation:

```
awk -v RS="---------" '{ORS=RS}/546-432/' file

Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff1
------
SomeStuff2
SomeStuff3
---------
Mycode_is-546-432
SomeStuff7
------
SomeStuff8
SomeStuff9
---------
```

Comment: awk -v RS="---------" '/546-432/' best solution for me thanks

Comment: the next step will be its using tail and principle like this

Answer (score 1):

Could you please try following.

```
awk '/^Mycode/{flag=""} /^Mycode_is-546-432/{flag=1} flag'  Input_file
```